# How to make 2 diffrent networks in router ping each other

Tags: cisco, ip, network, subnet

[image]

Hello i have this 2 routers how i can make them ping each other and alos the devices connected to them

Comment: This configuration doesn't make any sense if those IP addresses are configured on the link between the routers. The routers should have a shared network on the point to point link.

Comment: As Teun has mentioned the general practice would be to use a /30 for the interconnection with both routers existing on the same /30 subnet. This scenario is not viable as is, both routers need to share a subnet in order for ping or any type of layer 3 communication to take place. Years ago when I was newer Teun downvoted many of my questions or comments, that being said he knows his stuff ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routers need to have interfaces on a common subnet in your example.  If the addresses you show are for the common link, they are not in the same subnet.

You can either:

1. Change router1's interface to 10.2.1.2/30, or
2. Change router2's interface to 10.1.1.2/30

Answer (score 0):

Routers need to share an IP subnet with each other in order to communicate. If you use a link-only subnet you can use a /31 subnet mask, e.g. 10.1.1.0/31 and 10.1.1.1/31. A /30 subnet wastes 50% of its address range.

Since there seems to a another subnet behind Router1 that Router2 can't see, make sure you add an appropriate static route to R2, or set up a routing protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it i putted a serial connection between the 2 routers with 2 diffrent subnets and addes it to the ospf and the ping wotk in all places